# how to use gst_video_sink_center_rect to render video area?

Tags: c, linux, gstreamer

I want to use `gst_video_sink_center_rect` to let the video render the area I set. But I don't know how to use it. There is only `src` and `dst` rect. I'm confused about the result argument. How does this func work?

```
gst_video_sink_center_rect (GstVideoRectangle src,
                            GstVideoRectangle dst,
                            GstVideoRectangle *result,
                            gboolean scaling);
```